# How did Dumbledore beat Grindelwald?

Tags: harry-potter, albus-dumbledore, gellert-grindelwald

When Dumbledore finally faced Grindelwald in what was supposedly a legendary battle, Grindelwald had the Elder Wand, which is unbeatable, but somehow, Dumbledore beat him! How could he do it?

Comment: The elder wand is not unbeatable. If it was no one would ever lose it.

Comment: people were assassinated, that's how they lost it. In battle, it was unbeatable as long as it was with is true owner, which it was while with Gellert.

Comment: [You don't have to delete your questions just because they're duplicates.](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/7944/31394) A duplicate of a good question is often a good question in its own right.

Comment: “Unbeatable” is just the hype.

Comment: Well, I can at least think of 1 possible answer: The Elder Wand merely amplifies the power of a spell (probably 1.5x or 2x), so that when a spell is cast with the Elder Wand, its effects are more powerful when compared to the spells cast with a normal wand. For example, in Deathly Hallows, Harry asks Hermione to mend his wand, and this happens: 
“Please, Hermione, try!”
“R-Reparo.”
The dangling half of the wand resealed itself. Harry held it up.
“Lumos!”
The wand sparked feebly, then went out. Harry pointed it at Hermione.
“Expelliarmus!”

Comment: Hermione’s wand gave a little jerk, but did not leave her hand. The feeble attempt at magic was too much for Harry’s wand, which split into two again. He stared at it, aghast, unable to take in what he was seeing . . . the wand that had survived so much . . .

Comment: But then, in the last chapter of the Deathly Hallows, this happens: He rummaged in the pouch hung around his neck, and pulled
out the two halves of holly still just connected by the finest thread of phoenix feather. Hermione had said that they could not be re- paired, that the damage was too severe. All he knew was that if this did not work, nothing would.
He laid the broken wand upon the headmaster’s desk, touched it with the very tip of the Elder Wand, and said, “Reparo.”
As his wand resealed, red sparks flew out of its end. Harry knew that he had succeeded.

Comment: So if Grindelwald's "magical power level" is normally at 10, then the Elder Wand would amplify this number to 15-20, while Dumbledore's normal "magical power level" is 20, which is how he won.